# C# AutoMapper null reference?

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to map my model to exactly identical config. But always get this error:

> Type Map configuration: Model -> Config
>
> Property: Names   ----> System.NullReferenceException : Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Model, Config>().ForMember(x => x.Names, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());
```

Both of Model and Config have values:

```
public class Model
{
    public List<string> Names {get;set;}
}

public class Config
{
    public List<string> Names {get;set;}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the code that throws the exception?

Comment: is there an inner exception with an additional message & stack trace?

Comment: WHY does this marked duplicate?? Exception comes from Automapper Framework!